# Can not enable lock page in memory in SQL Server Express edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

For enabling `Lock Page In Memory`, I tried to do this: first of all I find my SQL Server account name with this code:

```
SELECT service_account
FROM sys.dm_server_services
```

This code returns:

```
NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS01
NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE
```

Then I open `gpedit.msc` and go to:

```
Windows Setting > Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment > Lock Page In Memory
```

After that double click on `Lock Page In Memory` and after open the window click on "Add User Or Group" button and past `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS01` and click ok and click "Apply" and "Ok".

In the end, I restart the SQL Server.

For validating that the `Lock Page In Memory` is in fact enabled, I use this code snippet:

```
--Check Lock Pages in Memory
SELECT sql_memory_model, sql_memory_model_desc
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

This code returns:

[image]

By doing these steps, `Lock Page In Memory` is not enabled.

What is the mistake?

Please help me - what can I do to enable `Lock Page In Memory`?

> My problem is to reading data. write separate post for that in this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305513/how-can-i-increase-sql-server-2019-express-performance-for-multiple-select-read)

Comment: Not sure it's available in Express editions, but you could try adding [trace flag 845 to the startup parameters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb970070-support-for-locked-pages-on-sql-server-standard-edition-64-bit-systems-388ddbde-1713-5e2b-4d96-8711499db3ef) to enable it.

Comment: Might need to restart the whole PC, have you tried that? Also which login is The actual SQL Server running as, is it `NETWORKSERVICE` or is it `MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS01`

Comment: I restart the computer several times

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, so voting to move to dba stackexchange.  But I don't think Express supports LPIM.  So you should add some details about why you want to, and perhaps there are some alternatives.

Comment: i want to use LPIM becuse have application nedd more then 100 per seccond `select` query. do you have better idea?

Comment: Please describe in your question, or in a new question a bit more about the scenario.  100 what per second?  Reads? Writes?  How big will the database be?  What happens if the rate falls below 100/sec?  What else is running on the computer? LPIM isn't really a solution to that in the first place.

Comment: LPIM is a solution to a different problem: other services (or virtual machines) running on the same machine and making SQL Server memory get paged out to disk. The number of `select`s you are doing is not really relevant

Comment: my problem is in reading data. i write seperate post for that in this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/305513/how-can-i-increase-sql-server-2019-express-performance-for-multiple-select-read)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lock Pages In Memory is only available in Standard edition and higher.

> The Lock Pages in Memory option is set to ON in instances of SQL
> Server **Standard edition and higher** when the account with privileges to
> run sqlservr.exe has been granted the Windows Lock Pages in Memory
> (LPIM) user right.
>
> To disable the Lock Pages In Memory option for SQL Server, remove the
> Lock Pages in Memory user right for the account with privileges to run
> sqlservr.exe (the SQL Server startup account) startup account.

[Lock Pages in Memory (LPIM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15#lock-pages-in-memory-lpim)

Comment: dose it available in Developer edition ?

Comment: @alirezasejdei Yes but you can't use developer edition in a production setting - so even if you switch to developer for doing **development**, you still cannot legally deploy that solution.